# React Native SwiftUI 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, swiftui

I'm trying to use a SwiftUI component with my React Native app, which appears to be a little complicated since I haven't found any documentation or tutorials for doing this online. Here are the files I'm using:

CategoryCardView.swift

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct CategoryCard: View {
  var name: String
  var body: some View {
      Text(name)
  }
}

@objc(RCTCategoryCardViewManager)
class RCTCategoryCardViewManager: RCTViewManager {
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  @objc var name: String = "Default text"
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    let swiftUIView = CategoryCard(name: name)
    let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
    return viewController.view
  }
}
```

CategoryCardView.m

```
#import <React/RCTViewManager.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RCTCategoryCardViewManager, RCTViewManager)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(name, NSString)
@end
```

NativeCategoryCard.tsx (in React Native):

```
import {requireNativeComponent} from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const NativeCategoryCard = requireNativeComponent('RCTCategoryCardView');

export interface CategoryCardProps{
    name: string;
}

function CategoryCard(props: CategoryCardProps) {
    return <NativeCategoryCard
        style={[{
            height: 100,
            width: 100
        }]}
        {...props}
    />
}

export default CategoryCard;
```

And then somewhere in my React Native code:

```
<CategoryCard text='hello' />
```

My app throws the following error when it tries rendering `<CategoryCard>`:

```
Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV7PalChat12CategoryCard_ setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc8718c7830
```

I don't really understand Swift and SwiftUI thoroughly, especially in terms of integrating it with React Native, so I apologise if I'm making an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not work - you have to use ObservableObject to  get prop change updates.

This [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-meets-swiftui-d1606a8e1681) describes in detail how to mix react-native and SwiftUI.

Also you can use my [make-react-native-package](https://github.com/iyegoroff/make-react-native-package) module to scaffold SwiftUI powered RN component:

```
$ npx make-react-native-package -p my-component -g username -t ios:swift-ui
```